# Google Drive Keep forever

Tags: google-drive, data-recovery

I've been hit by a ransomware and multiple thousands of my google drive files were encrypted and uploaded to Google Drive.

Unlike Dropbox, no global rollback feature exists on Google Drive.
For 30 days I can manually restore the previous version one file at a time via the Google Drive web interface and "Keep forever" setting in Revision.

Is there a script or a tool I could use to automate this process? Otherwise, I have thirty days to check that box manually for thousands and thousands of files...

Comment: Contact a Google Drive specialist through the Google Drive Help Center. Also you could use Google Apps Script and/or the Google Drive API.

Comment: Note that checking "Keep forever" won't roll back the version to the previous version—it will just save that version in the version history. The manual way of doing this is to (1) download the file, (2) upload the new version with the Manage Versions tool. Obviously, that would be impossible to do manually for thousands of files, hence, this question is very important! I agree with Rubén that you should try contact Google Support.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I did contact Google support and discuss over a few emails. They can't help and are not willing to do anything helpful expect explaining I have 30 days to roll back manually thousands and thousands of files. I am very disappointed. Beyond my case, I fear a lot of people feels their files are safe with Google Drive and obviously any ransomware just defeat the whole backup. Other part of my work was on Dropbox, Support was really helpful and I got all my files back in 24 hours after a rollback to a specific point in time.

Comment: @ahorn I found a faster way than downloading and uploading is to delete the last version and then the previous version becomes the current version. I could then sync everything again once. It gains a little bit of time but obviously doesn't solve the issue to manually check thousands of files.

Comment: @Rubén I am not skilled enough to create a goole script myself or use API. If a script existed to delete the last version from a folder and roll back to the previous one it would be very helpful.

Comment: While sometime answers on this site include links to existing scripts, this isn't a script finding / writing service, actually, questions asking for software (including scripts) recommendations  are off-topic on this site. I you could rewrite your question to include you search/research efforts to adapt/write a script yourself the question could be on-topic and there will be more chances to get an answer o this site. By the way, to ask for a software recommendation try [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @martin I'm shocked that Google Drive doesn't have a roll-back feature.